# ls -a lists files with "->" arrow I think they are linked how can I make my new file to change when referenced file is changed?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, ln

I have following files:

```
dirA/reference-file.ts

dirB/new-file.ts
```

I want `new-file.ts` to always change its content to match exact content as `reference-file.ts` when reference is changed.

For example when I do `ls -a` in my `dirB` I get files with `->` operator how can I replicate such behavior?

screenshot example:

[image]

Here is what I tried:

1. I create my new-file.ts

   ```
   cd dirB && touch new-file.ts
   ```
2. link it to reference file:

   ```
   sudo ln -s ./new-file.tsx ../en/reference-file.tsx
   ```
3. Output:

   ```
    ln: ../en/reference-file.tsx: File exists
   ```

Comment: Take a look at the `ln` command.

Comment: @steve I tried .sudo ln -s new-file.tsx ../en/reference-file.tsx and it does not work

Comment: that happens because you are trying to create a symbolic link to a file.

Comment: @AdminBee thanks admin bee that solved me problem if you wish contribute it as answer I'll accept it

Comment: In additino to AdminBee's answer, you could use a "hard" link: `ln ref-file new-file`. Then both filenames refer to exactly the same data on the disk.

Comment: Question: you want changes in ref-file to appear in new-file. What if new-file changes? Should ref-file change too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your approach is two-fold:

- The syntax for the `ln` command is `ln -s <original file> <link>`, so it must be

```
ln -s ../en/reference-file.tsx ./new-file.tsx
```

- The `ln` command *creates* the link file, so there must be no pre-existing file named `<link>`.

In your case, removing the (as of yet empty) `new-file.tsx` and running the above command should accomplish the task.

Comment: many thanks for explanation

Comment: For the second point, you can use `-f` to force `ln` to remove the target file before creating as a symlink. However, that doesn't work if the target file is a directory or a symlink directory, in which case, you'd also need the GNU-specific `-T` option: `ln -sT <original file> <link>`. Note that if `<original file>` is a relative path (which is often preferable), it has to be relative to the directory the link is to be added to, not the current working directory. See also the `-r` option of GNU `ln` to help you do that.